# POSIX Regex to match link to file in html <a> tag

Tags: c, regex, posix

I'm using the regex.h library for my C program.

I need to download all files whose link is stored in  tag in html data. So my first task is to extract its contents of "href" property.

I use this address to pactice
http://students.iitk.ac.in/programmingclub/course/lectures/

In its html content, there are many  tag like

```
<a href="1.%20Introduction%20to%20C%20language%20and%20Linux.pdf">
<a href="1.%20Introduction%20to%20C%20language%20and%20Linux.ppt">
<a href="1.%20Introduction%20to%20C%20language%20and%20Linux.pptx">
...
```

I write a regex string to extract the content in "href" property

```
char regex[] = "href=\"([a-zA-Z0-9%.,]*\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*{1,4})\"";
```

What I expect for the regex (I can handle full match and group match myself).

```
1.%20Introduction%20to%20C%20language%20and%20Linux.pdf
1.%20Introduction%20to%20C%20language%20and%20Linux.ppt
1.%20Introduction%20to%20C%20language%20and%20Linux.pptx
...
```

What I receive is only the first link (I just care about group match).

```
1.%20Introduction%20to%20C%20language%20and%20Linux.pdf
```

Nice day and thank you very much.

ps: I use REG_EXTENDED for regcomp()

Comment: Consider using an HTML parser like [Gumbo](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser).

Comment: Did you use the global flag `/g`? And you're probably better off just using `href=\"([^\"])\"`

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise it is off-topic.

Comment: a must in these cases http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5292302

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)